# Microsoft Graph - GraphServiceClient read email with another account

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I need to read a certain email but a different account.

The first example works

```
        string applicationClientID = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        string directoryTenantID = "dddddddddddddddddd";
        string secretID = "sssssssssssssssssssssss";
```

//Example 01: OK

```
        string email = "emailRead@outlook.com"; //WORKS: account 
        that will read the email = emailRead@outlook.com
```

//Example 02: Error need to read emailRead@outlook with account countService@outlook.com

```
        string email = "emailRead@outlook.com"; // DOES NOT WORK: 
        account that has permission to read email:  
        countService@outlook.com

        var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(
        directoryTenantID, applicationClientID, secretID,
        new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = 
        AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud });

        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new 
        GraphServiceClient(credentials);

        var inboxMessages = await graphServiceClient
            .Users[email]
            .MailFolders["inbox"]
            .messages
            .Request()
            .Expand("attachments")
            .Top(20)
            .GetAsync();
```

//I get the following message: Message: Access to OData is disabled.

Comment: Do you have any progress sir?

Comment: he question is whether it is possible to read the emailCompany@contoso.onmicrosoft.com through the accountCompany@contoso.onmicrosoft.com

another similar scenario:

if I have 2 registered users:
user1@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
user2@contoso.onmicrosoft.com

and has an email: email@contoso.onmicrosoft.com

how would i read email@contoso.onmicrosoft.com through user1 or user2?

Comment: Firstly, it's possible to read emails contained in `email@contoso.onmicrosoft.com`  on behalf of user1 or user2. The whole progress should look like this: provide microsoft authentication to let user1/user2 sign in first, then your app can based on the signing in information to generate an access token to call graph api and then get the emails. On this scenario, you can refer to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph).

Comment: Another scenario is that you don't want to provide a sign in module and you just want to read all the emails inside `email@contoso.onmicrosoft.com`, then you may refer to my code in the post, it used client credential flow so it doesn't need user to sign in, it generated access token on behalf the application itself. And please note, the 2 scenarios require different api permission, the first one require `Delegate` api permission and this one require `Application` [api permission](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code should work, except `messages` should be `Messages`. Here's my test result.

[image]

Firstly, when we want to check emails for a specific email account, we need to use client credential flow just like you used.

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_appid";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var inboxMessages = await graphClient
                        .Users["tinywang@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com"]
                        .MailFolders["inbox"]
                        .Messages
                        .Request()
                        .Expand("attachments")
                        .Top(20)
                        .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell us the settings are required in Azure portal  to run this code block.

Comment: The scope I used `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` means I'm using `application api permission`, so we need to [give api permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#application-permission-to-microsoft-graph) in Azure AD. @ShivShankarMaiti

Comment: When you give api permission you must have an Azure AD application now, or you have to [create an Azure AD app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal) and add [client secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret) for it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Actually my client has allowing us to delegates permission. Can help me bit what changes I have to do in your mentioned code?

Comment: you can't use my code when you use delegate permission. using delegate permission means you have to make your users sign in so that they can be authenticated and authorized to get the delegate permission. Pls find a [sample here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code). @ShivShankarMaiti

Answer (score 2):

- The problem might be with the Application Access Policy.
- Generally, if you use Application Permissions in OAuth for Microsoft 365, you can use the following instructions to further narrow down the permissions:
  [Limiting application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access)
- Permissions for Microsoft Graph applications (You might not require all of these):
  Mail.Read
  Mail.ReadBasic
  Mail.ReadBasic.All
  Mail.ReadWrite
  Mail.Send
  MailboxSettings.Read
  MailboxSettings.ReadWrite
  Calendars.Read
  Calendars.ReadWrite
  Contacts.Read
  Contacts.ReadWrite
- When an API call is refused access due to a specified application access policy, you may see the following error.

```js
{
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access to OData is disabled.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "<request GUID is here>",
        "date": "<UTC date format here>"
    }
}
```

- If your app's Microsoft Graph API calls return this error, check with the organization's Exchange Online administrator to make sure your app has authorization to access the mailbox resource.
- Helpful Powershell commands :
  Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy
  Get-ApplicationAccessPolicy
  New-ApplicationAccessPolicy
  Remove-ApplicationAccessPolicy
  Set-ApplicationAccessPolicy